# If Else Statements , AND OR logic operations, and text files (using Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, text-files, logical-operators

I'm having some trouble with AND and OR within if else statements. This is my code:

```
if subject == 'history' or subject == 'History' and unit == 'WWII' or unit == 'ww2':
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: coding hint: `userName, subject, unit, score, grade = hisWw2[:5]`

Comment: At first you should use parentheses to group the logical operators (`and`, `or`). The may not always be necessary but in complex expressions they are helpful to understand the expression

Comment: also, consider `elif`

Comment: all operators have a "weight" and "assosiativity" - they bind differently strong. Use ( ) to reformulate your logical assumptions so they bind in a way that fits.     FALSE and TRUE or FALSE  is always FALSE bexause `and` binds stronger then `or` does .... use () -- weight is the wrong word - brb - see answer for doku on pythons operators.

Comment: Yep the brackets are working thanks! I never knew you could put brackets around logic operators.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [operator-precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - some operators bind stronnger then others - to get your desired logical output you should use `(` `)` to structure your logical conditions.

Summarization:

> ```
> Operator                              Description
> lambda                                Lambda expression
> if – else                             Conditional expression
> or                                    Boolean OR
> and                                   Boolean AND
> not x                                 Boolean NOT
> in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==  Comparisons, including membership tests and identity tests
> |                                     Bitwise OR
> ^                                     Bitwise XOR
> &                                     Bitwise AND
> <<, >>                                Shifts
> +, -                                  Addition and subtraction
> *, @, /, //, %                        Multiplication, matrix multiplication, division, floor division, remainder [5]
> +x, -x, ~x                            Positive, negative, bitwise NOT
> **                                    Exponentiation [6]
> await x                               Await expression
> x[index], x[index:index], x(arguments...), x.attribute       Subscription, slicing, call, attribute reference
> (expressions...), [expressions...], {key: value...}, {expressions...}     Binding or tuple display, list display, dictionary display, set display
> ```

The ealier the operator the higher it binds. Please see the linked doku for subscription context